# Opening new view on button click

Tags: objective-c, view

I have a Navigation based Application named as diffView and in it  I want to open new view on button click. For this a have created a view as file-new file-cocoa touch class-UIViewControllerSubclass named next1.

In diffViewAppDelegate.h I wrote as

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btn1;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

and in diffViewAppDelegate.m-

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    CGRect bounds=window.bounds;
    UIView* view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:bounds];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [window addSubview:view];

    CGRect buttonFrame= CGRectMake(80, 240, 200, 30);
    btn1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [btn1 setTitle:@"space" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20]];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [view addSubview:btn1];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    next1 * nxt=[[next1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nxt animated:YES];
    [nxt release];
}
```

I am not getting any error but when I click on the button nothing happens.

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Try to change UIControlEventTouchDown to UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Answer (score 0):

How i imagine it:

1. In your delegate you load - alloc/init the `UINaviagationController` and set its rootViewController property or just using `initWithRootViewController:` method when you init the NavigationController. Something like that.

   ```
   viewController = [RootViewController alloc] init];
   nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
   nvc.navigationBarHidden = YES;
   [self.window setRootViewController:nvc];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```
2. In your RootViewController, from 'viewDidLoad:' method you create the button and add it to 'self.view' after that you implement the target selector and everything will be fine.

EDIT 1:

That is my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

That is my RootViewController

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    CGRect buttonFrame= CGRectMake(80, 240, 200, 30);
    UIButton *btn1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [btn1 setTitle:@"space" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20]];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender: %@", sender);
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes I have created the button in RootViewController but its not working.Even the button is not visible now. My code is like this-

Comment: CGRect buttonFrame= CGRectMake(80, 240, 200, 30);
 btn1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
 [btn1 setTitle:@"space" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [btn1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20]];
 [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [view1 addSubview:btn1];

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have created the button in RootViewController but its not working.Even the button is not visible now. My code is like this-

```
CGRect buttonFrame= CGRectMake(80, 240, 200, 30);
btn1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
[btn1 setTitle:@"space" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20]];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```